# Naming conventions for intents, events and contexts

Tags: naming-conventions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am wondering if there are any agreed upon naming conventions for intents, events and contexts in Dialogflow.

If there are none, then I would appreciate if you shared your own naming conventions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find that it's a bit of a contradiction to say 'it doesn’t really matter as long as it‘s easy to understand for others'. If there were naming conventions, it would be much easier for someone to understand a new Dialogflow bot.

---

Here's my take:

## Intents

I use dots to group intents and imply a hierarchy. The first part of the intent name is ideally just one word that clearly indicates the main subject of the intent. For example
`name` would be an intent that receives a user's name as an input. `name.confirm` would be the follow-up intent that receives confirmation of the name. `name.confirm.yes` would be the intent where the user has given confirmation.

This is in the context of a bot which is gathering contact data so the *input* function is implied. In a more mixed-type chatbot, you could add the type of intent as a first word to categorize your intents better. E.g. `input.name.confirm.yes` or `FAQ.shipping.overseas` or `smalltalk.agent.location` (*'Where are you?'*).

I use the same approach for fallback intents: `fallback.name` would be the fallback intent that is triggered when the bot is waiting for the user to input their name but doesn't understand the answer.

## Contexts

For contexts I use snake case. For example `awaiting_email` would be the context that is set when the bot is waiting for the user to input their email address. After I have the email address I would set a context `email` to carry forward the information so that other intents can use it as a context. Or if I'm collecting several pieces of data about the user, I will set the context `user` and other intents can access certain parameters e.g. via `user.email`.

---

I made a video about the topic as well: https://youtu.be/kgKuS2RJcy4

It's obvious that everyone is coming from a slightly different angle because their area of application is different. I'm sure we'll get to a common standard eventually!

Comment: thanks for sharing your conventions.  just a small point, i think awaiting_email is called underscore case or snake case.  Camel case would be awaitingEmail

Comment: Thank you! I have updated the term in my original response.

Answer (score 4):

I am going to answer this from perspective of a service based company's project.

In my project, we have used similar naming convention for intents as in-built small-talk intents, because its easy to understand and categorize. like `FAQ.Comapny.your_question`, `Buy.Drinks.coffee` etc.
(for some unknown reasons we capitalize the first letter of main categories of intents, in small-talk all letters are lower case as it should be).

For the events we have used similar notation for universal constants, like `INVOKE_EVENT`.

For parameters and contexts, we used snake_case i.e `coffee_cost`.

Basically, it doesn't really matter as long as it's easy to understand and replicate. But you should always have a basic structure which you and your whole team follows throughout the project.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any, unfortunately, and the system is flexible enough that it doesn't matter too much. Pick names that make sense (duh).

Although most of the examples use it, I *avoid* using a space in the name. I treat them more like function names, so having a space in it breaks my aesthetics.

I tend to group Intents based around what part of the conversation they're working on, which is managed through the use of contexts that are set, and separate the part and subpart designations by dots, so it vaguely looks like package designations. I'll have Intents named something like

```
calculate.fallback
calculate.number
calculate.operation
fallback
welcome
```

Where the "calculate" ones all have an Input Context of "calculate".

Most of all, remember that Intents (and thus their names) represent what the *user says* and *not* what your code does with that. This is the big way that it differs from a function name.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it really doesnt matter! As long as its easy to replicate in code and clear to see/understand for anyone else that might be working on your agent, then anything is fine. Generally though using typical coding notation such as CamelCase is probably not a bad idea.